# AppDynamics URL Monitor Extension Sometimes Doesn't Send Metrics

Tags: performance, monitoring, appdynamics

I have installed AppDynamics's Java Machine Agent along with the URL Monitoring Extension. Every day, for 1 or 2 hours, the metrics are not appearing on my metric browser. I checked the logs corresponding to those time periods, and I see that the HTTP Requests are being made and are getting back HTTP 200 OK responses. My assumption is that the extension is not sending over the metrics, but I am unable to understand the cause of it.

Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On that particular server, we have the .NET agent running as well. After shutting off the .NET agent, we were no longer having this issue with 1-2 hour gaps in the metric browser. Apparently, there is some conflict in having multiple machine agents installed on the same server.